# Are there any Nutch plugins to parse html body?

Tags: solr, hbase, html-parsing, nutch, html-parser

I'm using nutch 2.2.1 , hbase 0.9 for storing data and Apache Solr to search it.
These are my basic indexed fields

```
<float name="boost">0.10625245</float>
<str name="digest">5ef9408b2c4692d2c8c7ed24c1b38863</str>
<str name="id">org.wikipedia.it:https/wiki/1767</str>    
<str name="title">1767 - Wikipedia</str>
<date name="tstamp">2017-12-21T17:00:30.293Z</date>
<str name="url">https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/1767</str>
```

I want to parse and store the content of html-body of crawled web pages.
Have i to write a Nutch plugin to do it, or there are some config to enable it?I can't find any solution on Nutch site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you're missing the content field. If you take a look at https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/2.x/conf/solrindex-mapping.xml#L34 You'll see that one of the default fields is the `content`.

Check with the `bin/nutch parsechecker` tool if the content is being extracted for your URLs. And then test with `bin/nutch indexchecker` if the indexer is also extracting the content field. Lastly, check your mappings.

Keep in mind that the `content` will be the textual content extracted by the parser and not the *raw* HTML content.

Comment: I've tried to use this command `./nutch parsechecker https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix` and this is what i get 

 `contentType: text/html
signature: 82fab4560805b19a9585f90147247cb9
---------
Url
---------------

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix
---------
Metadata
---------`
Does This means that i' m not parsing any metadata?

My `solrindex-mapping.xml` is the same as the one that you linked.

Comment: I don't see the content there, what plugins do you have enabled in the `plugin.includes` setting on `nutch-default.xml` or `nutch-site.xml`?

Comment: in `nutch-site.xml` , in the `plugin.includes` setting i've got `protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|urlmeta` ; i've included only `httpclient` to crawl pages that uses https protocol. I'm not sure but i think that i added `urlmeta` too, i can't remember if is written by default.By the way, thanks so much for help, i'm new about Nutch-Solr architecture.

Comment: Try running the `indexchecker` command as suggested, the output should look something like: https://gist.github.com/jorgelbg/f64fc7e74f6f52c3f9ffe85369e5788f

Comment: with indexchecker i get that result, but broken :     `Unix - Wikipedia Unix Da Wikipedia, l'enciclopedia libera. Vai a: navigazione , ricerca Disambiguazi` i've tried to set `http.content.limit` to -1, and nothing happen.Furthermore, with some page of wikipedia, running `indexchecker` i get this error `Fetch failed with protocol status: GONE: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universit%25C3%25A0_del_Salento` .My regex-urlfilter.xml contain only `+.`

Comment: For that particular URL even with a curl command, I get an error 400, so probably you should take a look at the URL encoding.

Comment: i solved, now i can get content with a query in Solr.The problem was in the Nutch file schema.xml : in the line `<field name="content" type="text" stored="false" indexed="true"/>` i switched false to true.I don't know why indexchecker ive a broken result,  but it's not a problem.

Comment: Probably because the content was trimmed :) and of course you wanted to retrieve the exact content, that's why you needed the `stored="true"` part.